# Dextrose Sugar Cubes

Tags: sugar, cubes

I’m trying to make sugar cubes with dextrose sugar. I need the cubes strong enough to handle, but  want them to easily break down or really melt when placed in mouth.

What is the best ratio dextrose:water for the highest dextrose content per cube? And should I use a melted dextrose/water solution as wetting agent rather than just water?

Comment: Why don't you save yourself the hassle and buy pressed dextrose tablets instead of loose dextrose?

Comment: Those are rock solid. I’m trying to make something that breaks apart easier.